# How to add a comparison against last time period in Quicksight

Tags: visualization, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to create a dashboard where I want to showcase a KPI value for a month along with a comparison with the previous month. I have used the KPI visual for this. I have also added a date filter where users can select a time period.

However, the challenge I'm facing is that once I select the time period (Let's say April), the comparison disappears, because the entire dataset has been filtered only for April. I will have to select April and March for the comparison to be visible, however I have other visuals on the dashboard where I need to show data for 1 month only.

Is there a way on quicksight where I can show the KPI for a month and a comparison with the previous month in one view? This is possible in Google Data Studio, as below. Here I have only selected one month in the date filter, however comparison with previous month is still possible

[image: as shown here]